# Heroku commands throwing this error on mac: !error getting commands pid 29989 SIGSEGV (signal 11)

Tags: node.js, macos, heroku, terminal, uninstallation

This just started happening out of no-where. Did this happen to anybody else? I ran `heroku create app` and got this error  `!    error getting commands pid 29989 SIGSEGV (signal 11)`. This error provides absolutely no information. I use heroku all the time and could not figure why this error started happening. I ran `which heroku` and it showed heroku files where in `/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku`. Basically, I had to uninstall heroku and update node.js to get it working again. Steps I took to get heroku commands to work again.

- I updated node.js to version 8.11.1
- I unistalled heroku `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/heroku`
- I removed the heroku cache `rm -rf ~/.local/share/heroku ~/Library/Caches/heroku`
- And then installed heroku using the heroku desktop install download.

Even after all that the commands were not working properly, but I started to get a new error of `/usr/local/bin/heroku not found`. It seems I had to make one more removal to make the commands work again `gem uninstall heroku --all` and then magically it all started working again.

From what I gathered is my old heroku path was `/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku` and the new heroku path is `/usr/local/bin/heroku`. Perhaps heroku made an update that couldn't find my old path anymore. Best guess.

It sure was a lot to go through to get heroku working again so I thought I should share this for anyone else stuck. And hope if this happens again there could be a better easier solution for this. If there is one please reply.

I used this reference to help walk me through a clean uninstall for mac https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#uninstalling-the-heroku-cli

Comment: Also note that older versions of the toolbelt would put a path in your ~/.bash_profile. If that path entry is still there you will get a `No such file or directory` error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit late to this party, but answering in case anyone else encounters the same error. This error is caused by running an outdated distribution of the Heroku CLI (formerly known as the Toolbelt). Uninstalling your current version and re-installing the appropriate distribution from here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me!